# Perl / Apache errorLog message truncation

Tags: perl, apache

I'm having trouble with truncation occurring in Perl warn messages I'm sending to STDERR.

I'm using Data::Dumper to spit out some fairly deep data structures but they are getting truncated after around 8000 bytes.  I'm running under Apache 2.2 so it could be something going on there but I can't find any config setting that limits entries to the errorLog.  Data::Dumper is producing the full data I am expecting because I can see it all if I print it to the screen instead of warning it to the errorLog.

Anyone come up against this before?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the variable **$Data::Dumper::Maxdepth** as you need.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 2;

my $a = { 
    b => {
        c => {
            d => {
                e => 'Hello'
            }   
        }   
    }   
};

print Dumper($a);
```

It gives this output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => {
                   'c' => 'HASH(0x8cb688c)'
                 }
        };
```

Instead of default output without depth limit:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'b' => {
                   'c' => {
                            'd' => {
                                     'e' => 'Hello'
                                   }
                          }
                 }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not the issue.  Data::Dumper is doing it's job fine and working to the depth needed.  The issue is that where it produces say 40kb of output only the first 8kb makes it to the errorLog, the rest is truncated.  I could take DD out of the equation completely and just warn a 40kb string and only the first 8kb would make it through.

Comment: Oh, I see I misunderstood you. Could you show an example how you send record to Apache log?

Comment: No worries.  I'm using: warn Dumper($data)

Comment: I've tried warn from apache handler under mod_perl with 1Mb message and it had worked fine as expected. You should add more info about your environment.

Comment: Likewise, I've never had a problem before so as you say it must be something specific to this setup.  This is an Amazon EC2 development server running Perl 5.14.2 on Apache 2.2.22 under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I'm running under mod_perl.  I've actually started using Log4Perl as this solves my immediate problem but it would still be intersting to know what's going on here.